# Calculate the distance to an object through a pinhole camera - 2 approaches

Tags: geometry

The given image shows projection of a pinhole camera. 
Centered in this projection you can find a car with a height of $h=1.5m$. 
Additionally, we know that the image consists out of $27 \times 26$ pixels and the center of the car is horizontally is at $13px$, vertically at $11px$. 
 The focal length $f=15mm$ and the size of one pixel on the sensor is $0.15mm$. The goal is it to calculate the distance $d$ to the car based on the given data.

[image]

Based on the answer of https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo, we used the following formula.

$\text{Distance to object}(mm) = \frac{f(mm)\times\text{real height}(mm)\times{\text{image height}(pixels)}}{\text{object height}(pixels)\times\text{sensor height}(mm)}$

which in our case would be

$d = {{15*1500*26}\over{10*(26*0.15)}}={{585000}\over{39}}=15000mm=15m$

which would mean that the car is 15m away from the camera.

My question is if this is the correct solution or if not, how do I use that formula correctly?

I have some serious doubt about the solution because the proportion 15m compared to the car height compared to the image/projection height somehow seem wrong to me.

Additionally, I tried to construct this scene in a 3d-environment (with blender). 
I created a cube with a height of 1.5m, set the focal length to the camera, set the render proportions of the camera to $27 \times 26$, added a simple $27 \times 26$ grid right in front of the camera and moved the camera away from the origin until I see the same proportions as on the initial image ($6px$ above the car and $10px$ below it). 
The camera on the 2nd image now is  $1.76m$ away from the car (origin) so one of my 2 approaches to "solve" or at least "approach" the solution is definitely wrong.

[image]